# how to specify label for select in simpleform rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

```
<%= f.association :opportunity_status, :label => "Status", :input_html => {} %>
<%= f.select :source_type, options_for_select(["lead","vteam"],["lead"]) %>
```

On first line every thing is OK. On second line if I attach label the way I did in first line it show an error.

How can I specify label for select using simpleform?

Comment: Gotta accept some questions...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is because f.select is not a simple_form method and does not support :label

This should work for you w/ simple form

`<%= f.input :source_type, :label => "Lead or VTeam", :collection => ["lead","vteam"], :selected => "lead" %>`

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the only place I've found an actual, non-model simple_form example. Sheesh!

Comment: @BobWalsh The Simple Form docs while having some holes definitely differentiates between Rails' default form_builders, eg. select, and simple form's builder input and the ability to mix using both of them. [Custom-Inputs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers)

Comment: Thank you, from the bottom of my heart...I have no idea why the simple form docs are so bad.