# Rails simple_form label for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to set a label for the following line but I keep getting an error if I add label_method anywhere. label: is just ignored. How can I add a label for f.select?

```
<%= f.select :state_identifier, Location::STATE, { prompt: 'State', id: 'state' } %>
```

I tried the following but it doesn't format properly in form-horizontal, leaving no gap between the label and data.

```
<%= f.label :state_identifier, label: 'State' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because f.select is not a simple_form method and does not support :label

Something like this should work for you w/ simple form.

```
<%= f.input :state_identifier, :label => "State", :collection => ["a","b"], :input_html => {:id=>"state" } %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've been frustrated with this for the paste half an hour.

Comment: Did you just "copied and paste" from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242289/how-to-specify-label-for-select-in-simpleform-rails ?

Comment: @leandrotk It was mentioned in the rails doc