# How to move this text_method or label_method code from model to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, refactoring, simple-form

I'm currently doing this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :user
  def title_with_username
    "#{title} by #{user.username}"
  end 
end

<%= simple_form_for @tag do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :category_id, collection: Category.all %>
    <%= f.input :course_id, collection: Course.all, label_method: :title_with_username, value_method: :id %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to do the label_method all in the view without touching the model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to specify label for select in simpleform rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242289/how-to-specify-label-for-select-in-simpleform-rails)

Comment: it doesn't unfortunately

Comment: Just add code to build a title_with_username variable in the  view and assign it to the label

Comment: What is the purpose? Can you tell me why do you want to move that logic to view?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your existing select tag to something like

```
<%= f.input :course_id, collection: Course.all.map {|c| [c.id, "#{c.title} by #{c.user.username}"]} %>
```

You can build this collection array in controller and pass here as views should not be unnecessarily cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why but this seems to work

```
<%= f.input :course_id, collection: Course.all, label_method: lambda { |course| "#{course.title} by #{course.user.username}" }, value_method: :id %>
```